# Menu button not shown in action bar

Tags: java, android, android-menu

I have a straight-forward Activity which has to be compatible down to Android 4.0. Thus I want to show the old-style menu button (the three dots over each other). As far as I can see, there is everything which is needed for such a menu, but the three-dot-button does not appear.

My Activity:

```
public class MyCtrl extends Activity implements OnClickListener
```

Create the menus structure itself (this method is never called):

```
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu pMenu)
{  
  pMenu.clear();

  MenuItem prefsMenuItem = pMenu.add(0, 1, Menu.NONE,R.string.exit);
  prefsMenuItem.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel);

  prefsMenuItem = pMenu.add(0,2, Menu.NONE,R.string.prefs);
  prefsMenuItem.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_preferences);

  return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(pMenu);
```

}

...and handle it when a item is pressed (what never happens since it is invisible):

```
public boolean onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)
{
...
}
```

Any idea what could be missing or why the button is not shown?

Thanks!

**Update:**

I found the menu-functions onPrepareOptionsMenu() and onPrepareOptionsMenu() are not called when I have a call to

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

in my onCreate()-method. Neverhteless when this call is removed, the menu functions are called but the menu still does not appear. No theme is used, the App runs with default design.

Comment: What theme you are using? Can you post your styles.xml?

Comment: Can you post your updated onPrepareOptionsMenu()?

Comment: Finally: requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE) is the reason why the menu is not created. I have no idea why this menu now is created in top title bar and no longer at the bottom, but as soon as I remove this statement, it works

Answer (score 0):

if you want to create option menu than use this

```
 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, 1, Menu.NONE, "nilesh");

    // return true so that the menu pop up is opened
    return return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);; 
}
```

you have to crate menu Resource file in **res/menu/your_menu.xml**

Comment: Does not work. Even onCreateOptionsMenu() is never called when my Activity is created

Comment: did you create menu resource file ..?@Elmi

Comment: Nilesh Rathod: No, the menu is created programmatically as shown above. Nevertheless: this function is never called, so also a menu resource file never would be used!